# Phaserjs scaleManager add white strip on stage

Tags: phaser-framework

I am working with Phaser.js v2.6.2. When I try to use `this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;`, it adds a white strip on top of Stage area. If I remove `this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;` white strip is gone but stage not scaled.

I dont know what is the problem, I need some help here. Screenshot is attached.

My code is

```
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 250, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {
  game.load.image('background', 'images/gamebg1.jpg');

}

function create() {
  game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');
  this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
  this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
  this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
}

function update() {
}
```

NOTE: It only happen in emulator view, chrome.

[image]

Comment: In the emulator view... what happens in an actual tablet/smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think it has to do with the page giving margin and or padding to the html or body tags.
Try adding some styling to the html and body elements, Make the margin and padding 0 like so:

```
  <style>
     * {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
     }
  </style>
```

Comment: @raju Reading the post again, I think I misunderstood where the white strip was located. If my answer is not what you meant, I'll remove it